# Attempting to improve a C++ template API

Tags: c++, parsing, templates, packet

I am doodling with a binary packet parser leveraging template in attempt to create a "brick-by-brick" workflow. It is more about prototyping than performance. The basic idea is to configure a `PacketParser` with a bunch a `Field`s so it can parse a binary payload directly to a struct.

It is currently a satisfying MVP but I don't like the API:

```cpp
...
struct MyStruct {
    int value;
    void setValue(int v) { value = v;}
}

ValueField<int, decltype(&MyStruct::setValue)> myField(&MyStruct::setValue);
PacketParser<decltype(myField)> myParser(myField);

MyStruct out{0};
auto error = myParser.parse(data, len, out);
...
```

That *might* not look so bad, but it quickly gets worst when more fields are involved:

```cpp
ValueField<int, decltype(&MyStruct::setValue1)> myField1(&MyStruct::setValue1);
ValueField<int, decltype(&MyStruct::setValue2)> myField2(&MyStruct::setValue2);
ValueField<int, decltype(&MyStruct::setValue3)> myField3(&MyStruct::setValue3);
PacketParser<decltype(myField1), decltype(myField2), decltype(myField3)> myParser(myField1, myField2, myField3);
```

Yep... `decltype` everywhere. The reason it is this way is that `ValueField` must hold an instance of the method pointer (provided in the constructor) but the templated struct still needs to know the type of the setter before the constructor is called, because it could not be deduced so late, in my understanding.

```cpp
template <class T, class SetterType>
struct ValueField {
    const SetterType setter;
    ValueField(SetterType s) : setter(s){}
};
```

The macro workaround is an obvious solution to compress the API, but I would like to find a solution making it less verbose without that, either by using a different pattern, obscure syntax, pointer gymnastics, etc.

I wasn't able to come up with something less complicated than writing `decltype` everywhere so far.

Comment: `template<class T, class SetterType> ValueField<T, SetterType> makeValidField(SetterType setter) {return setter;}` - now you can deduce SetterType. Or use [template deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (C++17)

Comment: Wow that "Implicitly-generated deduction guides" section is a tough read haha! thanks mate